# Are legal notices in a login banner legally significant in terms of computer misuse?

Tags: privacy, legal

Is there any case-law where having or not having a legal notice ([example here](http://www.security-marathon.be/?p=746)) in the login banner of a system of nay kind made a difference in prosecution? The question is in consideration both of "hacking" - "you must not access without authorization" and privacy  - "everything is monited, no privacy expectations".

Comment: Im not a lawyer but when I went to uni my networking teacher said not to put welcoming MOTDs on routers/switches, as that will be used in court, if some guy gets into it and your software tells him welcome & have fun that's what he'll do

Comment: Not sure, if a doormat says "welcome", it doesn't mean you can break in.  No judge would go for that.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out "Offensive Countermeasures: The Art of Active Defense" by John Strand / Paul Asadoorian.

There is an entire chapter early in the book that covers the importance of login banners, including case law.

These are a few of the examples included.

- [US vs. Heckenkamp](http://itlaw.wikia.com/wiki/U.S._v._Heckenkamp) ([alternative write-up](http://www.sans.edu/research/leadership-laboratory/article/cyber-consent))
- eHippie vs the World Trade Organization
- [Susan Clements-Jeffrey vs Absolute Software](http://www.leagle.com/decision/In%20FDCO%2020120410B72.xml/CLEMENTS-JEFFREY%20v.%20CITY%20OF%20SPRINGFIELD,%20OHIO) ([forbes summary](http://www.forbes.com/sites/kashmirhill/2011/08/30/reminder-the-embarrassing-naked-photos-on-your-stolen-laptop-may-not-belong-to-the-thief/))

Comment: Hello, very interesting. Having briefly researched all three examples, I can't find that login banners played a crucial or any role in either of them. In cases 1 and 3 from what I gather there is a question of reasonable expectation of privacy vs "special needs" and the bargain part doesn't really come up. In (3), the case is settled so I'm not sure if any case-law has been established.

Comment: Also, I can't find any eHippie vs WTO case-law or even court proceedings.